# Docker fails to pull the image

Tags: python, azure

I am following this [tutorial](https://thenewstack.io/tutorial-build-an-end-to-end-azure-ml-pipeline-with-the-python-sdk/):

When I run it, pipeline gives me this error in the second (prep.py) step:

```
AzureMLCompute job failed.
FailedPullingImage: Unable to pull docker image
    imageName: ...
    error: Run docker command to pull public image failed with error: Error response from daemon: Get ... : unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
.
    Reason: Error response from daemon: Get ... : unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.

    Info: Failed to setup runtime for job execution: Job environment preparation failed on 10.0.0.5 with err exit status 1.
```

How do I authenticate? I already have access as a contributor so I should be able to pull the image.

Comment: you need to configure you docker host. where is your docker host ? is it self-hosted registry ? see here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/ how to configure docker.

Comment: it's not self-hosted. I just created a registry in cloud where it asks to create one. Sorry, Im really new to it and don't understand most of the stuff :p